# Unresolved reference to Koin's sharedViewModel()

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I am trying to lazy inject `sharedViewModel()` to my activity. For some reason my IDE cannot resolve reference. It can successfully resolve `viewModel()` but not `sharedViewModel()`. I can add it in imports but I can't use it.

[image]

Dependencies:

```
def koin_version = "2.0.1"
implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to use `sharedViewModel()` in `Activity`. According to [documentation](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/documentation/koin-android/index.html):

> The Activity sharing its ViewModel injects it with by viewModel() or
>   getViewModel(). Fragments are reusing the shared ViewModel with by
>   sharedViewModel().

To verify, you can check source code of [FragmentExt.kt](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/2609b60a0fe065052aee068bf269f7b479006d86/koin-projects/koin-android-viewmodel/src/main/java/org/koin/android/viewmodel/ext/android/FragmentExt.kt) and see that `sharedViewModel()` is `Fragment` extension. So, instead of `override val viewModel: PaymentViewModel by sharedViewModel()` you should use `override val viewModel: PaymentViewModel by viewModel()`